# How to create an outline for a group of shapes in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, shapes, outline

I have several freeforms that I formed to a group. Now I want the Shape Fill and Shape Outline color of all freeforms of the group to change based on a cell value. That I was able to do with the code below. However the outer Shape Outline of the whole group should always stay black, what doesn't owrk with my code. I found some code on the internet that might go in this direction but I don't really understand it and it doesn't work in my file (seems to work only for rectangle shapes). Any help is much appreciated.

I found a macro on the internet but this seems to be only for groups with a rectangle from:

Code I got so far:

```
Sub Region_Portugal()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim rg As Range
Dim rg1 As Range
Dim rg2 As Range
Dim rg3 As Range
Set rg = Sheet9.Range("N37")
Set rg1 = Sheet9.Range("I9")
Set rg2 = Sheet9.Range("I10")
Set rg3 = Sheet9.Range("I11")

If rg <= rg1 Then
    For Each shp In Sheet7.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 83"))
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next


ElseIf rg > rg1 And rg <= rg2 Then
    For Each shp In Sheet7.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 83"))
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 165, 0)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 165, 0)
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 165, 0)
    Next


ElseIf rg > rg2 And rg <= rg3 Then
    For Each shp In Sheet7.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 83"))
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Next


ElseIf rg > rg3 Then
    For Each shp In Sheet7.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 83"))
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Next

Else
    For Each shp In Sheet7.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 83"))
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
        shp.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Code I found on the internet:

```
Sub AddBorderToGroup()
Dim oShRng As ShapeRange
Dim oSl As Slide
Set oShRng = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

Set oSl = oShRng.Parent
With oSl

    With .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
        oShRng.Left, oShRng.Top, oShRng.Width, oShRng.Height)

        .Fill.Visible = False
        .Line.Visible = True
        .Line.Weight = 2 ' points
        ' etc for other line properties

    End With
End With

End Sub
```

The final result would be a map of the Iberian Peninsula where the different regions of Spain and Portugal are colored differently based on cell values. The map I use as template consists of freeforms for each provice. So I need to group together different provinces to get bigger regions. the regions should have a black boarder so that you can differentiate them in case there are several regions next to each other that have the same color.

Comment: Can you fill the freeforms now and do they act as you would expect?

Comment: The code you have looks like it is from a PowerPoint file. It should be relatively easy to rehash it to suit Excel. Without sitting down to test it can you change the reference from ...As Slide to ...As Worksheet

Comment: @Josh They act as I would expect with my code. But there won't be a black outline around the group of freeforms. I also replaced the Slide with Worksheet but I get an error message: "Object doesn't support this property or method.